# Apply EmitDefaultValue by default

Tags: xml, xsd.exe

I'd like to add the EmitDefaultValue tag to all properties generated from my xml schema. Does anybody know a way to do this when the class files are generated? The schema is quite large and going through properties one by one is not an option. If we have to regenerate the schema, we also lose or have to redo any manual changes.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you ever found a solution to this.